# What are the W and DSM codes for the following bacteria referring to?

Tags: bacteriology, taxonomy, database

In [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5338089/) the following bacteria are listed:

- Bifidobacterium bifidum W23 (DSM 26331)
- Lactobacillus salivarius W24 (DSM 26403)
- Lactobacillus acidophilus W37 (DSM 26412)
- Lactobacillus casei W56 (DSM 26388)
- Lactococcus lactis W58 (DSM 26390)
- Lactobacillus plantarum W21 (DSM 26401)
- Lactobacillus rhamnosus W71 (DSM 26396)

However, I can't find anything under the [NCBI's taxonomy browser](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi) or the [German DSM system](https://www.dsmz.de/collection/catalogue/microorganisms/catalogue) for either the Wxx or DSMxxxxx codes.

Where are the identifying central definitions of these strains?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I only took a look into the DSM numbers and obviously these are not correct. Have you tried contacting the corresponding author?

Comment: No, I'll try though. Thanks for the second look.

Comment: Update: I've asked the authors.

However, in the paper they say they identifed the strains by matching 16S data in this database:
http://rdp.cme.msu.edu/hierarchy/hb_intro.jsp

But I can't find the referenced Wxx or DSMxxxxx codes in that database under the stated species (you have to open up all the filters to the max and use the ORG:searchterm to search for named organisms).

Comment: \*they identified the closest *species* by matching 16S data

Answer (score 1):

After speaking to someone at Winclove Probiotics, who developed these strains (hence the Wxx code), I've found out that they are registered with DSMZ but they're "private" (hence why looking for the DSM codes doesn't work).

The names of the species listed are based on nearest matches of 16S data to species in the [RDP database](http://rdp.cme.msu.edu/index.jsp).